# Remove icon from MacBook toolbar

Tags: icons, toolbar

I have MacBook Pro 2015 running Mojave and it’s connected to two external Monitors. 
I have a few icons on Desktop toolbar like VNC, Insomnia, LastPass and etc that I want to get rid off. 
Various posts suggest simply keep 'command' button and move the icon out of toolbar but it doesn’t work for me. 
Any other suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Well I installed Vanilla free version and it did the job

Comment: It's nice that you solved *your* problem.   Now, can you add some details to the above to make it useful to other people as well?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Well I was not able to find solution to my request directly in MacOS.  Instead I installed app called Vanilla it which allows user to hide icons. That’s it